# How can I duplicate a mesh along a curve?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I want to outline a curve in the form of text with a mesh (UV-sphere, cube etc.). How can I do that while saving mesh geometry without using the Curve modifier?

Comment: That's what the curve modifier does. You can't really do anything.

Comment: @Paul see what CharlesL said above, the curve modifier is supposed to *deform* the mesh, It is possible you are intending this for something else. Can you explain what you are trying to create or do?

Comment: I want to make outline of text with mesh (UV-sphere,cube etc.). How can I do that saving mesh geometry without Curve modifier?

Comment: @Paul If I understand you want to *duplicate* spheres along a curve?

Comment: That's my idea.I want to create a text outlined with lamps like an old billboard on casino )

Comment: For Blender 2.8+, here's how: https://www.versluis.com/2019/07/duplicating-an-object-along-a-path-in-blender-2-8/

Comment: This helped a lot, @JohanWalles. Thank you!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Based on what you explained in the comments above, I think what you want are [Dupliframes](http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html). My answer is based on the example in the wiki.

In short, you add a curve to the scene and in the *Curve* menu under *Path Animation*, you enable *Follow*. *(You should also set the frames to a more reasonable number as needed such as 10 or so)*

[image: curve and curve settings]

Then add the object and [in the *Object* tab in the *Properties Editor*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/properties_editor.html) under *Duplication* **enable** *Frames* and **disable** *Speed*.

[image: duplication settings on new object]

Then parent the object to the curve or path, first select the object then the curve *(so that the curve is the active object)* and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and *Set Parent to Object*. After, you can select the object and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to reset its origin.

Finally, you can now change the orientation of the object by either rotating it *(either in Edit mode or Object mode)*. The arrangement of objects can, of course, be further enhanced by editing the curve. *(Shaping it into text etc)*

[image: cubes duplicated along curve]

Additionally from the same manual page linked above:

> There are many alternatives to Dupliframes. Which tool to use depends
>   on context.
>
> - To use a small curve as a profile and a larger curve as a
>     path, simply use the former as a Bevel Object to the latter.
> - To arrange objects along a curve, combining an Array Modifier and a Curve
>     Modifier is often useful.
> - Dupliverts can be used to arrange objects, for example, along a circle or across a subdivided plane.

[image]

Additionally, its worth noting that the additional objects are *instances* and not real objects, this will reduce the load of your scene and also allow you to be more flexible when adding more objects. Alternatively, you can *Make Duplicates Real* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>. All objects will now be ***real*** objects, but still linked copies. To change this, go to *Object → Make Single User → Object & Data* and choose *All*.

Comment: By the way. The solution you offered less loads Blender. Before I used an array to duplicate the meshes and Blender worked hardly...

Comment: Yes, iKlsR. Reduces. Now working with many meshes more comfortable )

Comment: @Paul yeah it should, the duplicates are instances and not real objects. In layman's terms the duplicate objects vertices don't really count towards the total scene size, it's pretty much visual.

Comment: Kind of annoying how unpolished this workflow still is 5 years later. You'd imagine there would just be toggle in curve modifier to only transform the origins instead of the meshes but nope. This is a good answer, though, albeit sadly I get pretty.. Interesting.. results at times when editing the curve.

Comment: @3Rton I'd daresay there might be a newer better way to do this. I'll poke around.

Comment: If you do find one I'm definitely all ears. I know you could definitely do it with something like Animation Nodes but default Blender wise this (Answer) is what I ended up doing. (My use case was using curves to place around circles to block out buttons placements. Array-Curve just never seemed NOT to deform the first circle. This method works well enough with simple curve, but complex curves the circles start going to pretty weird places instead of sticking to the curve.)

Comment: @3Rton That would be great as an answer as well!

Comment: No no I meant I couldn't find anything better than this workflow your answer outlined. 

Also, for my loss, it seems like they removed curve instancing on frames in last weeks nightly build..... Soooo yeahhh

Comment: Are dupliframes obsolete as of 2.8?

Comment: Doesn't work in 2.8. This does: https://www.versluis.com/2019/07/duplicating-an-object-along-a-path-in-blender-2-8/