# Applying Dupli-Objects

Tags: game-engine, modifiers, instances

Is it possible to bake dupliverts into one mesh for the BGE? (I have a large ground landscape that I use as the parent to duplicate trees, and the BGE doesn't support most modifiers.)

Comment: You can see some more info [here..](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve/511#511)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can turn all the duplivert objects into real objects by selecting the object with dupliverts and choosing *Object> Apply> Make Duplicates Real* from the menu in the 3D view, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> .

Then select all the individual objects and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to make them a single object.