# Is there a "copy on a support" function in Blender

Tags: modeling

I learned 3D modeling in Hexagon 2.5 and now have switched to Blender. There is a function in Hexagon/Utilities called "copy on a support" and I was wondering if there is something similar in Blender. Here is a link to a video showing it being used, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-YxGE4dB_4.

Ok, what it does is add many copies of an object to another object so you don't have to place all of them by hand. For instance, the bristles on a hair brush. There are many of them on a brush and it would take a long time to place them all.  This function places them there all at once, at the vertex/points.

Or say you had a mesh/circle and you wanted place all of the same kind of small object at each vertex facing the same direction you would use this.

---

Most excellent. I just clicked on the Dupliverts, Duplifaces links and that's the stuff it looks like, thanks.

Comment: seems to me that you are looking for [Dupliverts](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html?highlight=dupliverts), [Duplifaces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/duplifaces.html?highlight=duplifaces), and also particles using an object as dupliobjects.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dupliverts

From the [blender manual:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html?highlight=dupliverts)

> Duplication Vertices or DupliVerts is the duplication of a base object at the location of the vertices of a mesh. In other words, when using DupliVerts on a mesh, an instance of the base object is placed on every vertex of the mesh.

Alternatively use [DupliFaces:](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/duplifaces.html?highlight=duplifaces)

> Duplication Faces or DupliFaces is the capability to replicate an object on each face of a parent object.

Comment: Ok, I have been experimenting with the DupliVerts/Faces and now I have a second question. Is it possible to delete the original object you are duplicating without deleting the duplicated objects? Say if I duplicate a sphere on a circle and the original sphere is sitting in the center of the circle and I want to get rid of it but not the spheres that I have added to the circle. What I think I am looking for is a way to upgroup the spheres so I can delete just the one.

Comment: @PatrickOReilly to ask new question use the blue [ask question] link at the top of the page

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1482/applying-dupli-objects/1483#1483

Comment: Sorry about asking the second question in this tread. I think I see what I am looking for in the link posted.