# Array modifier with rotation value?

Tags: modifiers

Is it possible to create a turret like mesh like this using the bottom mesh and an array modifier? I want to be able to easily change the height of the shown shingle siding pattern. What I am basically looking for is some way to offset the mesh in a similar way to an array modifier, but with a small rotation value.

[image]

This is similar to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/rotating-each-iteration-of-an-array-modifier) but has some differences. That question wasn't exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Not sure if I got your question right but I made some rings in the past and made a video on how I did this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giiv3-7f4vM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer that you link to is a good solution, you can even use an object offset in two arrays to get the result you are after.

Start with one simple piece.

[image]

Add a solidify and array with object offset, rotate the empty to fit.

[image]

Add a second array also with object offset, move this empty up and rotate to offset the notches.

[image]

You can look at the [sample blend here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33801)

Comment: That is not what I was looking for. I want to be able to apply one array and add some variations to the individual shingles in the future, and I can't using this method.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that works for round objects. The base mesh will need to have an *Array* modifier and a curve modifier like so:

[image]

That just creates the mesh on the bottom, in order to make it repeat at that offset rotation, you need to add another *Array* modifier **before** the *Curve* modifier. Changing the *Count* will determine the height of the resulting mesh, I have it set to 5 for test purposes.

[image]

This makes the mesh able to be offset using the standard location offsets, and then it can be wrapped around into a circle with the *Curve* modifier. 
Here is the result:

[image]