# Rotating array objects around a circle

Tags: modifiers

I created an object and used an array modifier to create copies of the object in a circular shape as seen below (using the object offset option around an empty at the origin).

I'd like to be able to rotate the objects around the circle at the point where they intersect, but I'm at a loss as to how this could be achieved.

[image: Array modifier in a circle]

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Could you add more details/be more clear? Your question is a bit difficult to parce.

Comment: It may be hard to do what you want through an array modifier, it's probably easier to do it with independent object clones instead.  Alternatively, if you want to keep the array, enter edit mode in your arrayed object, place your 3D cursor over the circle, select all the geometry and rotate it around the 3D cursor by pressing "." (period) key.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks, the edit mode method works perfectly!

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/rotating-each-iteration-of-an-array-modifier