# How to position an office chair's legs?

Tags: modeling

Seriously. How? There are five of them. Do i just eye ball it and risk getting it all wrong or is there an exact way of achieving it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2402 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Spin tool.

Create 1/5 of the chair base then move the 2D cursor to the center of the chair.

The 2D cursor will be the center of the Spin.

[image]

In Top view select the 1/5 chair base and then use the spin tool to create the other legs.

Use the Spin settings as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I've always found a chair like this difficult to make simply because of it's legs!

Answer (score 0):

you could use a array, or just select one and press g+any number, to move that many blender units