# Extrude along path

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Is there a way to extrude an object or shape along a path/curve, so you get a solid object?  For example, a rectangle shape along a curve to get a long bendy sidewalk.

I feel this was in an older version of blender, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Also see [How can I duplicate a mesh along a curve?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve)

Comment: A more traditional extrude along curve add-on can be found here:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?254368-Extrude-Along-Curve

Comment: here you are <3 --->
[Bevelling a Curve](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Bevelling_a_Curve)

Comment: The legendary Blender tendency of not doing things like the rest of the world... extruding curve A along curve B is actually "beveling" B with A: "*Things are different, however, when you bevel the curve—that is, use some two-dimensional shape as a cross-section, and the line curve becomes a guide for extruding the shape into the third dimension*". [Source linked by user27048](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Bevelling_a_Curve).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image: Bevelled curve]

Use a bevel object in the curve properties > *Geometry* panel.

[image: bevel object settings]

You can use any curve to define the cross section of another curve. Make sure they are in separat objects because the object origin of the cross section curve will be extruded along the main curve. As you can see, you can put all kinds of independent curves into the *Bevel Object*

Comment: Sweet! How do you make those square shapes?

Comment: is that a question or a comment?  (:

Comment: Question, I'm unsure how to get sharp edges with paths.

Comment: If it's a question, make it a question. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: I know it is an old question but I had it too in 2017 and the answer is here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/object-follow-a-square-path

Comment: Note, the shape to project along the curve must also be a curve, not a mesh plane.

Comment: @ThorSummoner That's why I used the word 'curve' a lot. Never mentioned anything else.

Answer (score 28):

You can use an [*Array* modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Array) combined with a [*Curve* modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Curve):

[image]

The *[Merge](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Array#Options)* option merges duplicate vertices so that the resulting object stays as one mesh.

[image]

Note that when using the *Fit Curve* option in the array modifier, you may have to apply the scale to ensure this works correctly (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Scale*).

Comment: While this is very useful, and I'm likely going to do this to approximate what I need, I was more looking for something that works like 3DS-Max's Lathe, but in a line. E.G. A curve operating on another curve.

Comment: The benefit of using modifiers to achieve this is that it's a non-destructive method: you can turn it on and off, change settings etc. while the original curves stay the same.

Comment: I like it. But it's pretty weird and buggy at points, especially with tight curves

Comment: This method works in blender 2.9, whilst the other answer, unfortunately, does not - there is no more "Geometry" tab in object properties (unless I am missing something quite obvious).

Comment: @shybovycha, it's in the 'Object Data Properties' tab, not the 'Object Properties' tab. When using curves, the icon looks like a green curve with squares on its end points. The 'Geometry' section is in there.