# Repeating objects along a path

Tags: bezier-curves, modifiers

Is it possible to repeat my track object along a path? I tried using the method shown here [Extrude along path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/extrude-along-path?lq=1) using an array and then a curve modifier, but this happened when I added the curve modifier and chose the path as the curve object.

[image: image 1]

[image]

Answer (score 29):

In your scene it looks like the origins of the object might be messed up. When using the Array and Curve Modifier it is important to note that the origin of the curve and the origin of the mesh must be at the same spot. Also the mesh should have it origin at it geometry not somewhere else.

Here is how to fix it:

1. First let's make sure that your objects are not rotated or scaled by applying the transforms:
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> -> Rotation & Scale
2. Select the curve item in object mode
3. Place the 3d cursor at the curves origin, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> -> Cursor to selected
4. Select the mesh in object mode
5. Set the origin of the mesh to the geometry, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> -> Origin to geometry
6. With the mesh still selected move the mesh to the 3d cursor, <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> -> Selected to Cursor

[image]

[**blend file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28109)

Comment: Has any of this changed? CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+C doesn't open a menu, and after doing all of this it's still at the wrong place. (also, that pastebin link doesn't work anymore...)

Comment: In the latest version of Blender the CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+C doesn't work anymore. Just select the object and right click in the mouse, then Set Origin > Origin to Geometry.