# Scaling Dupliframes

Tags: scale

Is it possible to gradient scale objects using Object->Duplications->Frames?  I've tried Modifiers->Array however I get distortion when adding Modifiers->Cureve.  I've read [Duplicate object and scale across bezier curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75032/duplicate-object-and-scale-across-bezier-curve) with no success.

[image: Scale Box]

Comment: *Is it possible to gradient scale objects using Object->Duplications->Frames?* **Yes**, it is. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi Leander,  when I have a dupliFrame object how do I sequencally scale the objects?

Comment: Hi James, maybe I misunderstood the question. Setting two keyframes with different scales produces [the result](https://imgur.com/a/i7DqJ) you show in your image. Could you elaborate on ***sequentially***?

Comment: I’ve created a reptile scale that I would like to procedurealy generate over a path, that tappers (scales) off at the tail.  When I use follow path and curve modifier I get distortion.  If I use the duplicate frame to fill that path, is it possible to tapper the generated objects?

Answer (score 1):

You may scale the curve with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to make the objects grow gradually.
[image]

Add an object and parent it to the curve (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Object*). In the *Curve Data* header check the ***Path Animation*** checkbox. Check the ***Follow*** box also if you like to fit the objects to the curve's shape.
[image]

In *Object* header (with your object selected) set the duplication type to ***Frames*** and uncheck the ***Speed*** checkbox.
[image]

Adjust the *Frames* number in *Path Animation* panel as you like. Scale your object and apply Rot&Scale to it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>).
[image]

In *Edit Mode* select one segment of the curve, snap the cursor to it, enable *proportional editing* and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. 
[image]

You can now modify the curve's shape without deforming the objects.
[image]

Using this method I've created the row of scales (rotated the scale a bit to make it look better). Disadvantage of this solution is the scaled objects are not spaced evenly.
[image]

***NOTE:*** The other method, which uses inserted scales to different keyframes on a timeline (as @Leander suggested in his comment) works the same way.