# How to detail this cushions?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, sculpting

I am creating a photo realistic leather club chair. I've finished the blockout and im now moving on into creating the high poly. I plan on sculpting wrinkles and such on the chair, but i'm unsure as to how i can sculpt these stitches on the chair's cushion. Here is a reference photo:

[image]

i'm thinking of using an alpha but can't seem to find an appropriate one. Is their a way i can model this is?

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to sculpt the buttons but instead use a separate object for that. I would probably just create one and the use the array and curve modifier to position them. [Repeating objects along a path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8242/repeating-objects-along-a-path)

Comment: ah i dont want to sculpt the buttons i want to sculpt the zipper looking patern on the chair