# Rounded Ends (or caps) on Biezer Curve Pipe

Tags: modeling

Trying to make a simple bent hook with rounded that looks like the attached, but with rounded ends.

[image: Picture of bent hook with rounded ends]

However I can not get the ends to close with a rounded cap.  I do not want to use an array --the instructions given with the first suggested / help link (shown next) do not work anyways. Can anyone please help? [Pipe with round caps (ends)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/pipe-with-round-caps-ends)

Comment: Create separately Curve > Circle and use it as bevel of the curve, now the thickness depends on the size of the *Curve Circle*

Comment: It's not clear why the instructions from the question you've linked don't work, you just select 2 objects you like to be start/end cap. But you can model that [manually](http://i.imgur.com/EqRNED8.jpg) what can be not so good/fast, but working

Comment: @Marc do you mean a filleted end like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CSC6T.png ?

Comment: Yes please. In fact maybe even a little more rounded. It seems from all the tutorials I've found a beizer curve can have only a flat end. At one point I was able to close it somehow with triangles but I couldn't get those triangles to round outward. Thanks Zeffi

Answer (score 5):

[image]

1. Make 2 bend curve as seen in the image.
2. Make a small circle curve.
3. In *Object mode* select the bend curve and go to curve tab at the right hand.
4. In the *Geometry* panel under *Bevel Object* select the circle.

As soon as you click the circle you will get the tube shape. If you scale the circle you will find the tube getting thicker and thicker.

**If you want to fill the caps of the tube:**

In the *Geometry* panel under the *Bevel Factor* choose *Fill caps*.
If you check on the caps the opening will be closed and if you uncheck it the opening will be open.

Comment: this doesn't provide a rounded cap. this is only a flat cap. how do you create the rounded cap?

Answer (score 2):

Found a good answer to this question in this video: https://youtu.be/QuCVcg9UfOA

This is really flexible and doesn't require committing the geometry.

Basically it involves adding the two modifiers Weld and Subdivision to the curve.

The steps are:

1. Add a curve
2. Set Object Data Property Geometry Bevel to Round with Resolution set to 0 and Fill Caps set to true (checked). Set Depth to your desired size.
3. Add the modifier Weld with Distance set to a really low number like 0.001
4. Add the modifier Subdivision set to Catmull-Clark and Optimal Display set to false (unchecked)

And that should round the end of the shape.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish what you're trying to do is using proportional editing.

1. Select the ending edge loop and fill it
2. Poke the face
3. Subdivide with
   several cuts
4. Select the center group of faces or just the center
   point
5. Enable proportional editing
6. Move (locked to one direction) and
   adjust the "sphere of influence" until it looks as desired.

I've attached a gif of the process. This example has way too many faces but that can be fixed w/ some simple limited dissolving later.

[http://i.imgur.com/TRfjowS.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/TRfjowS.gifv)

I've also included a gif of the different menus I used during the process.

- Select Similar - SHIFT + g
- Faces - CTRL + f
- Proportional Editing and Options
- Use your scroll wheel to adjust the influence of the editing

[http://imgur.com/fLwo5g6.gifv](https://imgur.com/fLwo5g6.gifv)

Comment: Instead of having so long process and many verts. Just add a sphere cut in half and join it.

Answer (score 0):

Your pipes have arbitrary start and end locations... I would start over and do this:

1. Start with the ends of the pipes at easy locations (on the grid) and no angle (ortho = 0,90,180 etc)
2. Create UV spheres at the size of your desired pipe diameter.
3. Delete half of each of the UV spheres.
4. Rotate and move hemispheres into place, where they will be the end caps.
5. In edit mode select the edge of one of the spheres, duplicate and separate the selected ring.
6. Convert the ring to path (mesh to path convert).
7. Use the ring path as your bevel objects on the pipe path.

At this point it looks pretty but edits to the pipe means the caps aren't where they belong. Start by making the pipe the parent of the caps, which fixes pipe's object movement. When end cap vertices are edited, you must be careful to duplicate the movement and rotation edits to the end caps... kind of a pain but feasible.

Answer (score 0):

One option Ive found simple and workable is to create by extrusion the last vertex. Set it's width to 0.3, move it off slightly, finally extrude once more, the closing vertex and set it's width to zero.

Example:[image]

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is over five years old but I’m going to answer it for anyone looking for this in the future (like I just was). The answer is actually dead simple. Convert to mesh and bevel.