# How do I make a curved solid line?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm a newbie to blender and I'm trying to make a curved solid line. I want it to be perfectly curved, as half a circle. I want it to have thickness and be round on the tips. Think of a sausage.
I've tried multiple ways, but couldn't do it.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What way have you tried and why were you not satisfied? I don't think there's any easy way to do it with a bezier curve, you'll need to stick 2 half-spheres to each end of the curve, if you work with mesh you can use Skin + Subdivision Surface modifiers

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55302/rounded-caps-on-a-bezier-curve-pipe https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53523

Answer (score 4):

Set up a Bezier Curve to be a hemi-circle like this:
[image: White board of Bezier Curve]

Building a "Hot Dog" shape by deforming a UV sphere (the red tube) and then applying a curve modifier to it should get what you asked for (the blue tube)

[image]