# Generate curve caps with geometry nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to model a bunch of fiber-optic cables, as seen in many images: with the end of the cable lit.

The cables per se are easy to model: A bunch of curve circles spread around a bigger circle, extruded along a curve.

AFAIK there is no way to control the curve caps, so I used the original cable "slice" from the former paragraph and instanced on the end of the curve with the Endpoint Selection node.

The problem is that I cannot align *the rotation* of the cap to be aligned with the end of the curves:

[image]

I tried Curve Tangent with Align Euler to Vector, and now it faces correctly at the end of the curve, but the rotation along the path doesn't match:

[image]

Help me, BlenderExchange! :-) Thank you all

Comment: If you go via _Curve to Points_, that node hands you a rotation: see [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243415/35559)

Comment: You, sir, are a genius :-D Thank you! Works ferpectly :-) It would be great if you can answer the question to flag it as such.

Comment: np. This is _almost_ a duplicate question.. just UV the original's answer, if it helped.