# Make profile curve resolution variable across the spline

Tags: geometry-nodes, splines

With geometry nodes I would like to convert spline into mesh in a way, where result mesh (tube) profile resolution is based on the main spline factor. Like for example on start of the spline (factor 0) with resolution 4 and on the end (factor 1) with resolution 12. Is it possible?

I have tried to use resample curve operation to be somehow affected by the main spline factor, but it never worked for me.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don’t expect this to be able to work, but it’s still worth a try I guess.

Comment: Do you want sudden changes 4→8→12, or do you want it to go 4→5→6→7→8→9→10→11→12?

Comment: I want it to go gradually 4-5-6-+

Comment: Generally I want to create tree trunk and branches, which have less resolution as they grow, as the mesh needs to be optimized to run in-game.

There is also second question to that, which I ll probably ask as another post (variable density of curve segments (cuts) based on it's own factor). This all is possible in SpeedTree software and I would like to achieve it here too.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'll start:

[image]

This move vertices to one point, the earlier in curve the more vertices. Then it merges them. It changes the shape of the spline:

[image]

The next step could be a calculation by perhaps aligning euler to curve tangent (captured just like the factor is captured above), plus aligning it to curve normal - like I aligned the caps [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294496/60486):

[image]

Then you could sample the beveling curve.

I didn't do it however, because that's not the way to go. The way to go is to select some points, and move them towards the next point. This brings two problems:

How do you select the points? One method would be to apply a ping-pong on the beveling curve (circle) factor and see if it's above a threshold. This probably shouldn't be a ping pong, more like multidimensional ping-pongs:

```
010101010101010101010101010101010101
111000111000111000111000111000111000
111111111000000000111111110000000000
```

Summing those ping-pongs you should get a value and check if the current factor is more or less than that (normalized) value.

Second question is how to figure out where to move the point, but I guess by transforming the formula used to generate that ping-pong, to calculate the distance to a value below the threshold, and sampling that factor to get the index...

Would the effect be better than merge-by-distance, remeshing or decimate modifier? I doubt it, that's why I'm not really motivated to finish this answer

Comment: Thx for trying! Obviously I am no geometry nodes guru, but to me it looks like geometry nodes framework is not ready for this task. Yet this feature is present in all better tree procedural generators. So I kind of hoped it is gonna be doable here :/ .

Comment: Oh it's definitely doable, but I don't really see a point. Do you know the decimate modifier?

Comment: I added 2 new pictures that illustrates what I need. One from "Tree It" software and one that I just quickly done manually in Blender. Decimate modifier can't be used...it creates too messy topology with also kind of randomly/partially removed edge loops. Edge loops removal should be controlled separately.