# Transfer Normals onto geometry nodes point instances

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

[image]

here i have an object that i have scattered spheres on with distribute points on faces and instance on points, as you normally do. you can see that the spheres have their own normals. is there any way to transfer the normals of the object upon the spheres so that they have the same shading as the surface? i already figured out how to get custom normals created in the geo nodes on the spheres, but i don't know to to capture these normals

Comment: Those spheres have their own rotations, correct? In my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294496/60486 I also store normals, but then I also store instance rotation and in the shader I rotate captured normal by that rotation to get the true normal. Or just consider not rotating the spheres, since there's often no reason to do so.

Comment: then capture the normal on the instances and just use that directly (Attribute: Instancer)