# Geometry Nodes: How to set curve line rotation to another curve's tangent?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

[image]

**Description:**
In this scene, I want to create a series of vertical planes along a horizontal curve circle. These planes must be created using a vertical curve line node. They were turned into 2D planes with a 'curve to mesh' node, using a curve line node along the X-axis as profile.

**The problem:**
I am trying to get these planes to face inwards. They need to be oriented to the tangent of the curve circle (annotated in the 3D view). How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

*Curve to Points* node gives you *Rotation* output exactly for that purpose - just connect it to the instance rotation:

[image]

If this doesn't align the instances properly, you can either:

- add an intermediary node *Rotate Euler*,
- (better) just modify the *Direction* of the *Curve Line*.

If this still doesn't work for some reason, you could e.g. take the cross product (*Vector Math*) of node of the tangent and e.g. $<0, 0, 1>$ vector, and pass that to *Align Euler to Vector* node, to obtain a rotation aligned with Z axis…

You can also chain two *Align Euler to Vector*s, like I've done [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294496/60486):

[image]

Comment: Strangely, whenever the planes are pointed straight up, they become solid gray and lose their rotation. However, any other orientation works fine. Here's some screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/tskWy9o

Comment: @Thomas Gimbal Lock perhaps.