# GN writes an attribute that intervenes in the normal direction and provides it to the shader，

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders, normals

I want to use gn to achieve the effect like Susan's below. How can I use gn to create an attribute that interferes with the normal direction and pass it into the shader? thank you very much
[image]

Comment: Just *Store Named Attribute* of *Vector* type, and use the *Attribute* node in the shader to read it. Here's a real life example where I do it: [Rounded cap on Curve with Geo Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294496/60486)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't quite understand. The Susan on the right in the picture is the result of a normal map I drew. The effect on the left is what I want to use GN to achieve. How should I make a normal map like the one on the right in GN?

Comment: If you know how to calculate the texture but you don't know how to send it to the shading - then that's what I answered. That's how I understand the title of your question. If you have a specific pattern in mind that you want to reproduce, then the question should be "How do I achieve this pattern?" (which would be a bad question because of the usage of "this", so ideally we could find a name describing this pattern) - and I'm not sure how to achieve this particular pattern, I would try saving on each face coordinates of its corners and use that in the shader…

Comment: Yes, I actually have two problems. You have solved the first one for me. After I downloaded your blender file, the first problem has been solved perfectly. thank you very much! The second question is how to use GN to make a normal map so that it looks like an oil painting (the second monkey head is an oil painting monkey head I made using a non-GN method)

Comment: [link](youtube.com/embed/s8N00rjil_4?feature=oembed)  the second monkey effect is here