# Creating edges between sequential vertices using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a mesh that only consists of vertices - no edges or faces. This was achieved by importing x,y,z coordinates from a .csv file.
Can geometry nodes create edges between the vertices by using the index of the spreadsheet?
So, procedurally an edge is create between vertex[0] and vertex[1],vertex[1] and vertex[2] and so on.
I haven't been able to really get my head around geometry nodes as yet. Every question/answer I've found to date just doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple using the "Points to Curves" node:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome and so easy. Is there now a node to make the curve smooth but the points stay where they are?

Comment: @Symo ask another question :) Consider how the points define corners of the curve, so by definition you can't [smooth](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/306616/60486) the curve without using these points. Make sure then to explain in your question exactly what you mean by points not moving or by curve smoothing. You could convert the curve to bezier with auto handles, it will smooth the curve, keep the points in place, but also drastically change the look of the curve.

Comment: yes, bezier curves / auto handles did the trick. Thanks again.