# Caps on Curve (Geometry Nodes) not included in my Shader / Capture Attribute complete Geometry

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders

Sorry for the newbie question:

I need rounded Caps on curves using Geometry Nodes. So I followed various tutorials and ended up combining elements from these two https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EV9qgvz7yRU and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dC4YrxYhJzU

Now, I've created a shader with a gradient that follows along the objects, following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDKlfxmnnIQ). It works fine, but the rounded caps don't seem to be integrated into the object. Which – to my limited knowledge – is logical, as the "Capture Attribute" Node gets its "Geometry" Information from "Group Input"; which does net yet contain the caps. But I cant figure out how the change this.

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions how to get my shader to include the rounded caps? Thanks you!

EDIT: I've uploaded the blend file:
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: I didn't click on the links provided, but it is one of very suboptimal Youtube tutorial for caps, that inspired me to write my own (much better of course) solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/294496/60486

Comment: Thanks! I've uploaded the blend file. I'm aware that there are better solutions for caps. I've seen so many tutorials. Crazy that there isn't an easy option for this in Blender. Good link to get an idea for a different approach.

But the main question would be, how to include the caps in my shader.

Comment: i will never understand why people are watching yt videos without voice who explain what they are doing (and additional with annoying music). There are so much better video tutorials out there e.g. from Erindale or Johnny Matthews. With the exception if you really don't find tutorials with voice...but normally you will find one.

Comment: True. That's why i had to use two tutorials. The one w/o voice also is vertical and you can't see what they are doing. Thanks for your recommendations. 

But I included the YT videos to explain my setup. The real questions is about the use of the "Capture Attribute" node and how I can include the entire object, so my shader (with a gradient following the curve) also works on the rounded caps.