# rigging flexible hose connected between two objects

Tags: rigging

I have a hose between two objects, one end is stationary and the other end is connected to a cylinder that pivots, how can i make the hose flex and stay connected to both when the cylinder pivots?
I have searched every where for a solution to this but am unable to find one, as any tutorial i have seen doing this is on a different version of blender which dont seem to translate over to the newest version.
I can make the hose flexible on its own if i separate it from my model but cant find a way of connecting it at both ends, so i think im kind of on the right track but maybe overlooking something really obvious and simple?

Any help or a link to a v3.0 tutorial would be greatly appreciated

Comment: One approach is to use an armature of two bones and a hook modifier.  parent the columns and the curve to one bone and set the hook on the other.

Comment: Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150637/how-to-create-wire-between-objects .  That's 2.79 IIRC, but nothing has changed in regards to that answer.

Comment: https://youtu.be/-2HCxy4Kh4E -> Polyfjord is - in my opinion - one of the best Blender tutorial makers at all. He explains it there pretty well.