# Rigging a Martian tripod - Leg struts

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

[image: Martian war machine rigging]

I am fairly new to Blender and finding my way around. A project I have is to rig and animate this model. I do own this legitimately.

So far I have rigged the body, upper legs, lower legs and feet however I have not found a way to rig these supporting struts shown selected in the pic.

For clarity the body is the large bulk of the model with the green 'eyes' section. You are looking at the front view and the leg in question is the left L. You can just about see the bone label Leg_L going from the body to the 'knee'. Going down from the knee is the lower leg bone. Bones are Displayed-As 'B-Bones'. The orange selection is an expanding strut which will pivot at each end and extend/retract as the Leg_L and LowerLeg_L bones move.

I had expected to be able to add a bone through the strut and parent one end to the body and the other to the lower leg but it seems you can only attach to one parent. Im not sure where to go from here.

There is also the matter of the blue/purple flexi hose near the 'knee' joint which I am hoping can be rigged as well but again to me it looks like I need to attach it to both the Leg_L and LowerLeg_L bones.

Each component of the model is a separate part at the moment, as you can see the strut is made of two parts itself and neither linked to the leg or body.

Any advice on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd have thought that searching for a tutorial about rigging pistons on YT should find what you need. For the hose see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252060/rigging-flexible-hose-connected-between-two-objects.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86804/rigging-an-umbrella-like-object/86921 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102990/how-can-one-rig-a-stirling-engine-piston/103000#103000