# moving a USB cable along a curve

Tags: animation, modifiers

So I think this may be fairly easy but I am not finding the solution. I want to move several USB cables along a curve and have them plug themselves in. Naturally I thought to just model out the cables and then apply a curve modifier, the only flaw is I do not want the head of the cables deformed... So how can I get the cable to follow the path and deform while having the head follow that same path and not deform?

Thank you so much!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53523/how-do-i-add-a-non-deformed-end-cap-to-a-tube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a youtube video that does what you are wanting in some aspects, and it worked for me, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRAfhJQFjRo&list=PL2DcM9Gsef16GjHLpFtYS1A0iBlsCoq6G ,  i Would reccomend starting at 2:12, thats when he uses the curve