# How do I animate a hose along a path without deforming the lead it is attached to?

Tags: path

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.rab3d.com/tut_blen_2-63_hooks.php 2

And got a nice hose and fitting with a tangent connection.
For an animation I’d like to move the whole thing along (inside) another, bigger hose.
The bigger hose is open on one side to show how the fitting plus small hose move along inside)
Like a camera mounted at the front of a long lead (camera should not deform...), inside some flexible tubing.
But I can’t seem to animate an empty along a path (‘follow path’ constraint works, but gives weird effects for the rest of the curve)…

Any ideas?

An example file here: https://mediviz.nl/tijdelijk/TubeTest.blend

Erik

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53523

Answer (score 0):

I added a rig with a bendy bone to the front of the hose and that works.