# How to round off corners using a curve circle

Tags: modeling, animation, bezier-curves

I have 2 objects in my scene. one semi circle which is from a mesh and I applied subsurface modifier and got round corners. The other object B is a curve circle, but is there a way it can have rounded off corners like the semi circle object A? The reason why I'm using a curve is because I can animate it using the bevel start and edge which is convenient.

[image]

Comment: I guess you have no other choice but to create half circle objects that will stick to each tip of the curve

Comment: so I'm guessing the best option is to just to use a Boolean mask animation or build modifier, because the corner edges of the curve cannot be achieved in a more less tedious way?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how boolean or build would help, maybe tell a bit more about the whole project, you could also array an object along the curve, in that case you give it a cap start and cap end

Comment: See how the speed metre animation light has rounded corners on the tips of the circle. Using the curve is great, but its got flat ends, and there is no option to get these rounded off edges.  https://ibb.co/8YKJF6h

Comment: Actually I think you have 2 solutions: Use a bezier that you extrude, with a Subdivision Surface modifier it will round the tips. Or use a mesh object that you array along a curve, and give the Array a Start and an End Cap wich will be a round object.

Comment: You could also use a curve and use a mesh that will follow exactly the tip of the curve with keyframes

Comment: Or... since you need only one end of the arc to extend, it could simply be a rotation from behind a mask.

Comment: Can you please post screen shots with your recommended 2 methods. I'm doing something wrong, nothing is working out for me, Thanks.

Comment: This question seems related. It's not an answer to your question, but more like a sugestion for a possible workaround...
The mesh looks good, but it's sadly not using the bevel-curve approach. :/ 
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/pipe-with-round-caps-ends

Comment: are you open to the array solution? in that case Quacksilber has given a link, but it means you use a mesh + curve, not just an extruded or beveled curve

Comment: yes just using a Subdivision Surface modifier (firs solution I cite) won't work if your curve is too big