# Object follow a square path?

Tags: bezier-curves

Okay so I know about half of how to do this.
So I made a plane, then converted it to a path with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.
Then I made another plane and made many loop cuts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> and the scroll wheel.
Then I used the curve modifier to make the non-curve plane follow the curve plane.
But it cuts corners:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be that you have to set the curve handles to to the Vector Type using the <kbd>v</kbd> key to bring up the menu.  You can change the handle type individually or all at once depending on what is selected.

[image]

I am just guessing here since you did not upload a .blend file to PasteAll.org with the link pasted here.

Comment: Actually, thats exactly what I was looking for! thank you!