# Extrude along an edge loop by vertex

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges

I have two mesh objects.

I want to extrude one object in such a way that it traces another object.
I could have sworn I'd seen this done in a tutorial once, but I can't remember how and can't find it via googling or other Stack Exchange posts.

[image]

In the image, I've extruded once along the edge and once continuing away from the loop. I'd like to have each extrusion match the vertices of the loop in both position and rotation.

I looked at the possible duplicate, and it's based on both objects being curves. I was able to convert the loop to a curve, but not the circle quarter. I'm not sure why. And trying to recreate it as a curve opened another can of worms I'm too inexperienced to deal with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extrude along path](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/extrude-along-path)

Comment: I'm not dealing with curves. But maybe I should...

Comment: The second object shouldn't need to be a curve.. Given that the second object is simply a quarter of a circle, you probably don't even need the second object. Try setting the *fill* to *back* and increasing the bevel width and resolution: http://pasteall.org/pic/79117

Also note that the edge loop can probably be easily converted to a curve with Alt C

Comment: @gandalf3 Awesome technique! Thanks! I needed to also set Shape to 2D and Modification Offset to -.2 to get the exact shape I wanted. But it worked. I'd still like to know if it can be done the way I asked though. Edit: also, I just realized that it's not as precise as if I used meshes...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another way you could use bezier curves, modify your curve until you get your desire form and transform it into mesh, so you can extrude after that.