# How to copy an object along a path

Tags: modeling, transforms, path

I'm new to Blender, coming for 3DS Max, is it possible in Blender to copy an object along a path with specific parameters? Such as count of copies and orientation?

Comment: Welcome Georges :) Does this help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/extrude-along-path?lq=1 ? ?

Comment: You're welcome. Which one?

Comment: My question were related to your first link, I didn't notice the second one actually until you asked :D

Comment: Actually, looking around, this one gives a better answer, The second answer "not the script" by Igor T.