# How do you extrude a mesh so it sweeps another object

Tags: vertices, bevel, bezier-curves

I'm working on a bobsled roller coaster in No Limits 2 and I have a 3d spline that follows the track. I'm using blender to make the half cylinder that replaces the existing track to make it look like it is a real bobsled. I am having trouble making the track that follows the spline. This is what I have so far. [image]

When I try bevel the semicircle along the path, I get failed set value. I've also looked at the post about extruding along path and that hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extrude along path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2866/extrude-along-path)

Comment: That didn't work for me, I kept getting failed set value when I copied the steps in the answer. @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: You must use a curve object