# How do I prevent object distortion when applying a curve modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

This is the profile of the object I'd like to wrap...

[image: Object to wrap.]

Here is the object's profile after being wrapped...

[image: Object profile after wrapped to curve.]

Is it possible to prevent the distortion? The following post here: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?293735-Dublicating-an-object-along-a-curve-without-distortion-Array-or-DubliFrames did not affect my object. It seemed very promising, maybe I'm missing something?

Note: I have applied the scale to both my object and curve.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve?lq=1

Comment: I guess the only way is to add armature- then parenting objects with them. And - finally adding Ik solver and spline IK to armature so it will slide along curve.

Answer (score 32):

You can use a proxy mesh as the curve object, then use *Dupli faces* to place an object at each face. This has the added advantage of using *instances*, which are more memory efficient than the array modifier.

[image]

1. Add a plane and set it up with the curve and array modifiers:

   [image]
2. Parent the actual object to the plane (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>).
3. With the plane selected, enable *Faces* in *Properties > Object > Duplication > Faces*.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the actual object'?

Comment: @jikbik The object you intend to duplicate

Comment: In 2.8 the step 3 is under `Object > Instancing > Faces`, then you'd also like to uncheck both "Display / Render Instancer" checkboxes.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the blocks from intersecting?

Answer (score 12):

The *Curve* modifier will always distort the object according the curve's curvature.

If you want the object to follow the curve (using the curve as a path to move the object along it), you can add a ***bone***, parent the object to this bone and add the *Follow Path* bone constraint:

- Go to *Add* menu (<kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>) > *Armature* > *Single Bone*
- Place it at your object's center position
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> to **Pose Mode**
- Select your object, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the bone (in this order)
- Parent the object to the bone: hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> and choose ***Bone***
- Select the bone, and go to ***Bone constraints*** tab in the properties panel
- Add a ***Follow Path*** constraint (right-hand list, titled "relationship")
- Choose your *Curve* object in the **Target** input
- Check the ***Fixed position*** box, and use the ***offset*** slider to move the object along the curve:

[image]

Comment: How do I repeat along the curve? I tried adding an array modifier to the object -- makes sense to someone as educated as me, but probably doesn't make sense to a blender pro.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution supposed the arrayed objects are relatively simple and regular:

[image]

Demo file is **[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ojv5B6Lb-3UTB1VVZhQkF1bW8/view?usp=sharing)**.

I have to admit that such solution is very limited, but if it's enough to serve your particular case, then try it. :)

Comment: Fast and easy solution - the Solidify and Bevel modifiers are superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comment on Polosson's answer, you may want to convert the curve to a mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, then Mesh from Curve/Text), set it as the parent to the object you want along the curve (select the object, then the curve, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>), and then enable duplication (in the object panel for the curve, in duplication, activate "Verts").

Play with the curve's resolution before converting it (in the Curve panel) to tweak the density.