# Curve modifer has unusual inversion

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to deform a "chain" to follow a NURBS curve, but there's a weird inversion at the bottom of the loop.

[image]
[image]

I've tried various applies, scales, subdivisions, but the basic issue remains.

Thanks for any insights, I'm stumped.

Comment: This is similar to my question here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8235/why-does-this-strange-deformation-occur

Comment: FWIW When I deleted everything and started again with what as far as I can tell was exactly the same arrangement it worked as expected. But I still have the old file, I will try checking the centres as suggested. Tx.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8235/why-does-this-strange-deformation-occur) that 'stacker' pointed me to below, I did indeed manage to fix this by ensuring the curve and target geometry shared the same origin.