# Armature chain follow a path

Tags: armature, rigging, bones, constraints

I'm trying to create a chainsaw type of animation using bones. I may be approaching this from the wrong direction but I would like to create a chain of bones and have them follow a path.

I used the SplineIK constraint to create the shape but I'm not able to get it to animate correctly on the Bezier circle. [image]

This is about as far as I got, but I can't actually move the bones.

[image]

I'm able to get one unparented bone to move around the circle but never a chain of bones.  Any advice would be appreciated! I really hope I can get this to work!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8235/why-is-the-curve-modifier-deforming-strangely

Comment: It doesn't look like they are using bones.  I'm trying to create a rig rather than use than apply an array modifier to a mesh.

Answer (score 5):

**Constraints**

- Consider a follow path constraint.  Which can rotate objects along the curve.
- The curve hugger bones can have parents but must NOT be connected.  The cutting teeth can be connected to the hugger bones.  I assume the geometric normal bones are cutting teeth.
- I do not think Spline Constraint is favorable.
- Consider a conform modifier.  No rotation.
- If you are really daring you might consider rigid body chain links.  Some people consider these situations unstable.

Comment: I just saw this today, great advice.  I ended up doing exactly that last night.  I attached a helper object to a path follow constraint. I then created separate bones for each helper.  This solution is ideal because the bone actually rotates as it spins along the path.   Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did.  The oval is a path. I attached each square object as a helper and offset them evenly around the path.  Then I attached a bone to the helper.  It's simple but I did the job.

[image: solution to chainsaw problem]

Comment: Exactly what I needed.   Thank you!