# DupliFrame is deforming the object

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am trying to make a domino movie, but i got stuck while using this dupliframe feature
It keeps on deforming the object!
I thought this is used when you just want the object aligned and oriented along the path, but not deformed...

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliFrames

I am using blender version 2.71 did the feature changed during the updates or something??

[image]

the highlighted mesh is domino shaped mesh an i am trying to duplicate it along the curve without any deformations as the screenshot shows.

Comment: Could you show us what you've got so far, and what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier

Comment: Could you upload the blend file?

Comment: how can i upload the blend file??

Comment: @Overnoobed Upload it to [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/) or a host you like, and put the link here.