# Array Along a Curve Without Deforming Mesh

Tags: modifiers

[image]

How to set array modifier along a curve without deforming the cubes?

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier