# Mesh gets deformed when an array of spheres deformed along a curve :(

Tags: mesh, modifiers

So I took some edges from another model that I want to turn into a curve for spheres to follow. I did this by duplicating the edges, seperating them into a seperate object and then using the alt + c to convert to a curve.

As you can see, there are quite a lot of points on the curve in edit mode, not sure if this contributes to the weird deformed meshes I get, if so is it just a case of decimating?

[image: Lots of points on the curve!]

So when I add a curve modifier (after using an array to make lots of spheres) I get this result, you can see the spheres get deformed round the tight bend of the dips in the curve, elsewhere they are fine.
Can anyone point me in the right direction to a solution!

Thanks in advance!

[image: Spheres are deformed!]

Comment: try using dupli faces http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8236/2816

Comment: There's a way to do this by parenting the object to the curve using "follow path", not the constraint which has the same name. Then by editing the animation paths of both the object and the curve, I can't create the answer right now, I'll do it asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to make an object be duplicated along a Curve (path) is by parenting the object to the curve using (Follow Path):
1- Make sure the object and the curve's origins are at the same position, better to have the curve's origin at the beginning of the animation flow. Select the object then the curve, you need the curve to be the active selection.
2- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, choose Follow Path, this is different that Follow Path constraint, the only common thing is the name.
[image]
3- Select the object, go to Object menu, under Duplication, choose Frames and un-check Speed.
[image]
4- Select the curve, go to Curve menu, under Path Animation, set the amount of frames, the object will be duplicated according to this amount, check Follow, if you want your objects orientation to follow the curve.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Georges, that worked a treat, thanks a lot, much appreciated!!

Comment: You're most welcome @Msmith1991

Comment: @ georges it works with the square its not working with the sphere can u plz go to my link and solve my problem http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66272/how-to-rotate-object-along-path-path

Comment: @atek looks to me you already had an answer using a third method with dupliverts, anyways, if you still want to use this method, make sure you apply the scale to the object and the curve, then try it again using the exact same steps