# Placing object along spline without deforming

Tags: modifiers

I like to place dominos along a spline and keep the mesh undistorted. At the moment i´m using the curve modifier and the array to achieve this. Pleased with the placement i am, less pleased with the deforming of the mesh. Is there a way to clamp so that mesh keeps it form or do i have to go a different route?

Comment: Curve modifier is a deform modifier. Look here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55523/mesh-gets-deformed-when-an-array-of-spheres-deformed-along-a-curve

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier

Comment: Thx lemon, exactly what i was looking for!