# Distorted array mesh

Tags: modifiers

I am trying to propagate an array along a curve. The mesh that is being replicated as an array is an iconosphere. Attached is an image of the array and the curve. You can see that almost all the iconospheres are distended to various degrees. There are probably just 2 that are uniform in size. I am guessing the distortion is due to the intricate curve and number of vertices along the path. Is there anyway around this?

[image]

Comment: I found a few answers to similar questions. I will try those out and post update.

Comment: array a simple plane object instead, and then use the sphere as *Dupligroup* on the plane

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! None of the answers I found on SE worked for me. Here are the links I looked at:

- [How to rotate object along path path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66272/how-to-rotate-object-along-path-path)
- [Mesh gets deformed when an array of spheres deformed along a curve :(](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55523/mesh-gets-deformed-when-an-array-of-spheres-deformed-along-a-curve?rq=1)
- [How do I prevent object distortion when applying a curve modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier)

Here are the instructions that worked for me:

https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliframes.html

Dupliframes to the rescue!

Comment: Just adding a link is not an answer. Please further describe how you solved your problem for the benefit of those in the future.