# Hair Particles - Can I recalculate the initial rotation every frame?

Tags: particles, hair

So i have an animated ocean, Shrinkwrapped a hexagon grid over it and spawning a buoy on every vertex.

[image: Blender Viewport - Buoy Grid Preview]

I used hair particles en set the initial rotation to Normal-Tangent which works great. The issue I am having is that I can't get it to have the buoy recalculate the normal on every frame (only set its Initial Rotation) So the buoys don't rotate.

When I go to a later frame en change any setting it recalculates the normal again and it is good, but only for that frame.

Anyone have a fix or know a better way to go about this?
Thanks!

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100642/wave-modifier-physics

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys I already have to solution, I just had to check to regrow option.
Thanks anyway!