# how to make rigid body react to the wave modifier or animated shape keys in blender ? (Or let's say animated vertices/faces if that matters )

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, displacement, shape-keys, rigidbody

1. I have created a plane with animated wave modifier, applied scale and location as well.
2. On top of the plane there are few cubes with active rigid body.
3. I want when the wave comes cubes on top of  the plane reacts to the wave. (Jump or rotate or even move a little bit. Do something)
4. But rigid body cubes do not show any response. Towards plane, they don't react at all.

**5.Things that I have  already tried**

**(i)** Making plane passive with animated. Tried  both options convex Hull and deform, with mesh and final.

**(ii)** Above things with cubes also.

**(iii)** Making plane a collision serface also.
(Tried cubes collision also)

**(iv)** tried exporting and  importing  .mdd file. (Wich creats animated shape keys for you ) but still right body does not reacts to the shape keys.

**(v)** Several Techniques that are used to float a boat on top of ocean modifier.
But still that sticks to the plane, and not the results that I want.

**(vi)** Tried making both objects active. One with animated turned on (plane).

**(vii)** I thought there could be a problem with wave modifier. So I tried deforming the mesh with animated displacement modifier.
But still no rigid body seems to be working.

**One thing that worked so far**
Only soft body reacts to this deforming mesh.

1. Making the plane collision serface
   And all objects above soft body.
   Then these soft Bodies reacts to the mesh quite good.

One could say that work with the soft body.

**But**

I have a cube with cell fracture applied, which has created a 1000 random  meshes out of that cube. And I want all those pieces reacts to the wavy serface beneath them.

To apply rigid body I can go and just select all 1000 of them and say *Object >Right Body > Copy From Active*. And all of them will have my desired settings.

(Can't be done with soft Bodies as far I know. There are ways, but not efficient.)

Imagine doing soft body settings for 1000 meshes individually.

After all you can achieve hardness through soft body, but results are not like rigid body. You have more faces in your mesh and it'll start to  wobble like jelly.

If anyone knows the solution, please tell me that how can I make rigid body reacts to the animated vertices/faces  or deforming mesh in Blender.

If there is no way please tell me which software can do this.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100642/wave-modifier-physics

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Duarte. But I have seen this post already, it is good for sticking an object to surface but there is no solution for rigid body simulation with animated vertices.