# How can I duplicate an object along a path?

Tags: modifiers, path

I created a long mesh object and I selected an edge, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate then made it a separate object by pressing <kbd>P</kbd>. Continued with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to convert curve from mesh. So far so good. But I want to use the curve as path to duplicate an object along the mesh object but I cant seem to make it work. I tried a few ways with using array and curve modifier also using the duplication tab in the object property set on Frames.

It does duplicate the object I want but not along the path. Just what seems to me like random places or straight in a line. Maybe I did something wrong along the way? I wonder if this has something to do with pivot point and if so how would be a smart way to make the pivot points of both objects the same?

[image]

Comment: There could be some unexpected problems with converted curves from meshes like Mean Radius on some random values, spline type set to something not allowing changing handles etc. So if converting mesh to curve then in its Edit mode make sure to clean it, so setting Spline type to Bezier (or what's needed), setting Curve radius and Mean radius to 1.

Comment: Welcome to BSE. I added keystroke tags to your question. You can click the _edited ... ago_ link or the [edit] link to check how I did it, to learn how to use it yourself. You may also want to take the [tour]. And as for your question, it might be easier to determine what's wrong if you included some screenshots of what the objects look like, or even the .blend file. You can upload .blend files to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: Hey thank you both for your help. I uploaded the .blend with the linkDuane provided. I also used the link to my question but Im not sure f that worked.So heres the [link](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3380/). Would be nice if one of you would take a look. Its pretty barebone so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

The curve and the object have been rotated and scaled in object mode but the **transformations have not been applied**. (select the curve in object mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to apply rotation and scale, then do the same for the dragon's fin)

Why apply transformations? Read the following link: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

The second issue is that the curve and the object you want to duplicate along it have their origins in different places. That will only give you headaches.

**The origin for the curve and the replicated object must be in the same place**.

Move the object so that it is in the exact same place as the curve. Select the curve, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and select "Snap Cursor to Selected". Then select the Dragon's fin and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> again, but this time select "Snap Selection to Cursor".

Both objects are now in the same place and the array and curve should work the way you want.

[image]

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Now it generates along the curve as I wanted but it also deforms the dragon fin a lot, makes it longer also the rotation isnt quite right as well. How can I fix that?

Comment: Deformation is one of the side effects of using curves. You might want to try dupliframes: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve/511#511 or duplifaces https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier