# Keeping array objects straight when duplicated along a twisted curve

Tags: bezier-curves

I have a fence curve which goes down a hill and fence posts duplicated along it using the Array and Curve modifier.
How do I stop my fence posts tilting with the angle of the fence? I would like them to remain realistically upright as they go down the incline.
The post's origin is on the exact same place as the fence's and duplicated with the Array modifier, using the fence curve in the Curve modifier.

**Issue**

[image]

**Fence properties** (Bevel Object 'fence to curve' is the shape extruded along the curve to make the fence itself)

[image]

**Fence post properties**('Fence Curve.RIV...' is the fence curve)

[image]

Comment: There's some unavoidable degree of curving effect when arraying with Curve modifier, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier

Comment: Array a simple plane object then use particles to place posts on every face instead, that way you can place them upright or in any other direction. curves will always deform the face, no way around it.

Answer (score 2):

I finally have an answer to this. I wanted to make pillars for my roller coaster track, and I needed them to be vertical as well and after a lot of search found the solution. Here is how it looks

[image]

The way is to NOT use *Array Modifier*/*Curve Modifer* but instead parent the object (fence posts) to your curve ( <kbd>Ctrl P</kbd>), and then use *DupliFrames* (after disabling speed). This way, it treats each of your posts as separate objects and then you can use *Limit Rotation* to zero degrees on all axes. This will keep them vertical.

I just implemented this and it totally worked. Let me know if you need more details. I think the idea is that modifiers treat the set of fence posts as a single object and thus you cannot *Limit Rotation* on them separately. Using *DupliFrames* treats them as separate objects and thus you can limit their rotations afterwards. Sorry for the wordy reply without any images. Other blender experts can comment if this should work.