# Bending a chain without deforming the links?

Tags: modifiers

So, I've done the anchors on my ship, but the chains needs to be bent around the winch at the bow. How would I accomplish this without actually bending the links?

Kind Regards

Skull Kid

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved! I used DupliFrames. By selecting the chain links, I used parenting (selecting by Right click on the chain links, then selecting the curve and parenting it to the chain links with Ctrl+P and choosing Follow path). Then you can go to the Object tab. under Object, find the Duplication tab, open it and choose "Frames". Then play with the settings to get the best result. To get it to follow for example, a Bezier curve. Select the object you want to follow the curve and go to Object in the 3D view panel. Then in that menu, choose Clear > Origin (or simply select the object you want to follow the curve, and choose Alt+O).