# Christmas lights Soft/Rigid body curve physics

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, soft-body

I am trying to model christmas lights that are going to be moving around a lot in the animation. So, I want to make the wire a soft body curve to keep render time low. Using a mesh was too slow. The light bulbs would also need to be curves. But the bulbs need to be rigid bodies so they don't deform when they interact with the scene. I am having trouble finding a way to attach the bulbs to the wire since I am working with curves. Attached is my blend file so far.
[Blend file](http://www.filedropper.com/christmas-lights)

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5910/599