# Avoid curve modifier distortion when making a chain

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, distort

I am aware that this has already been asked [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier), but in this case I am using a chain, which has been made using tori offset by 90° each time using an empty object.

However, when I do this, you can see that the chain links are distorted:
[image]

One idea I had for a solution was making the array come from two linked links, so that no rotation was needed, but this made it look a lot worse when only every two links could rotate.

I tried using the bone method shown in the link above, but this did not allow for duplicates.

How can I make it so that each link retains its original proportions whilst having the 90° offset each time?

By the way, having it going in a circle wouldn't work as the shape I intend to wrap it around is irregular.

Also, I'm quite new to Blender so I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: You could use bones or bones and Spline IK but could you please tell a bit more about what you want to do? Is it supposed to be animated or is it just for a picture?

Comment: I intend to have some rigid body links hanging down, so I will replace the vertical side links with rigid bodies. The only animation will be with physics, but only on some of the chains, and only very minor swinging.

Comment: You could create your chain manually then give the links that are supposed to move a Rigid Body physic. You could even animate with bones if it doesn't need to be Rigid Body, that would make it even simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it!
Using [this video](https://youtu.be/ZgdobdXzKM4), I made the vertical links and then duplicated and rotated it to make the horizontal links and set the right number of them by changing the frames in the data tab of properties of the bezier. The links used DupliFrames to do this with 'speed' unticked.

[image]

Here I'm using a bezier circle (although the concept remains the same).

[image]