# Array and Curve modifiers Issues Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm currently working on a T-44 as a side project from my Airbus A319. It's all been pretty straight forward up till now. But I've ran into two problems that I could not solve.

Although I have seen many solutions to the array problem, I can't get mine to work.

The two problems I have are:

1_ I have a gap that I can't close. I've tried many things, although I got close It's just off.

2_ My track deforms around the front and back wheels.

Thanks,

Karl.

[image: Settings for the modifiers I Used]

[image: Curve Settings]

[image: Track Deformation]

[image: Track Gap]

[image: Curve Layout]

[image: Test Render]

Comment: You can fill the gap, by increasing the lenght of the model a little. Curve modifier always will bend the model. If you want them stay straight you have to use dupliverts instead of these modifiers. http://builder.openhmd.net/blender-hmd-viewport-temp/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html

Comment: I agree with @FFeller: you can use a duplivert set to faces like shown here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier.

This won't probably work if you want to make an animation, and in that case I would use a _follow path_ constraint with a quick python script to generate all those object instantly

Comment: Thank you, I've managed to solve the issue now