# Why the mesh get shrink with follow path

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a mesh and a curve. Selected the mesh and curve, Ctrl+P to follow path. Why the mesh get shrink down its original size. (Note : I have attach my file in that i tried to set the origins of the mesh and curve at starting). I tried with the array on the curve same issue. Any suggestion or help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent object distortion when applying a curve modifier?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question was a bit misleading, you were using the follow path function, which is made for animation I suppose, when you were actually trying to duplicate your object along the curve without deformation.

Since 2.8, you can't use the *Dupliframes* method anymore, so here is another one:

Create a single vertex, give it an *Array* modifier with *Constant Offset* (not *Relative Offset*), give it a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Object*:

[image]

Keep the single vertex object selected, go in the *Properties panel > Object > Instancing* and click on *Vertices*. Now select your pylon object and parent it to the vertex object, it should repeat like that (modify the pylon orientation if it's not good):

[image]

If you want the pylon to change its direction along the curve, choose a plane instead of a single vertex, and click on its *Instancing > Faces* insteand of *Vertices*.

Former answer:

You must have scaled your curve, because if you go into *Edit* mode you'll see in the *N* panel that its vertices have a *Mean Radius* of 0.239, you need to bring it back to 1. Now your object still rotates so make it rotate 90° on the X axis.

[image]

Comment: As per the steps above i followed. After adding array its going good as soon as i add curve the 1st mesh get flat from the base. And rotating on x 90 not working in edit or object mode . https://imgur.com/a/xC9z3oB and increase count of array got this result https://imgur.com/a/iLqRQGM

Comment: I thought you wanted your object to follow the path, which is supposed to be used for animation. If you want to array along a curve without deformation, do not use Array + Curve modifiers, use Instancing

Comment: anyway to make it follow on curve with array modifier

Comment: You need to give the Array and Curve modifiers to a plane, then select the plane and in Object Data > Instancing > Faces, then parent the object you want to duplicate to the plane.

Comment: @moonboots, maybe this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier (duplicate so...)

Comment: @ lemon, yes that's it, I've edited my post though (and gave the single vertex solution which may be useful)