# How can i achieve this model with pops on it?

Tags: modeling, topology

I`ve made a lot of models. But stuck here...
How can i achieve this curve figure with pops on it.
I can make this curved model of Ice cream. But how to attach this round pops on its surface with smooth holes, with exactly distance and etc.?
I tried with Array - Curve along this path, but i get "shattered" topology...
Maybe someone knows the way to get this figure.

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5910/how-do-i-prevent-object-distortion-when-applying-a-curve-modifier

Answer (score 0):

You can create this mesh and this spiral curve:

[image]

Then give your mesh an *Array* modifier, a *Curve* modifier with the spiral as object, and a *Subdivision Surface*. Decrease the radius of the top vertices of the curve:

[image]

Comment: Yeah,i tried this. But u see, some pops were deformed.. so i cant solve this, to get exactly round pops/holes (

Comment: the sphere can be another object that is instanced