# stretching problems with curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am building a tank tred using a combination of the array modifier and curve modifier.  The problem that I'm having is that the tred is experiencing uneven stretching when it bends around the corner wheels.  Is there a way I can fix this  (maybe something is wrong with my bezier curve?)

Attached are the curve points and also the settings on the tank track

[image: track with wheels hidden]
[image: modifers]

Comment: With the curve modifier you will see see documented shape distortion or uneven stretching.   You will not be able to eliminate that in the general case.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6486/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/32692/599

Answer (score -1):

Consider a path constraint.  You may want a script for placement of objects.

Consider a rigid body constraint.

Neither of these are trivial to do from starting point zero.

Curve Modifier by comparison is less work.

Comment: I am very new to blender, can you give me some tips or a tutorial on a rigid body constraint?  I am a good programmer and I have about a year of python experience

Comment: Please add some details as to how to set up the various constraints you have mentioned.