# Duplication along curve with Mirror modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, mirror

After i created a duplication along a curve with [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve) I want to mirror the whole thing. If I add a mirror modifier on the curve and the object it doesn't the object is not transformed along the curve.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you can click the Apply button on the Mirror modifier for the Nurbspath object? AFAIK, it's not allowed for curves.

Comment: No and I don't even want to apply it. Why should I?

Comment: Well, because you said " If I apply a mirror modifier on the curve...". Please consider to refine your answer, make it easy to understand, thus we could be able to help you more.

Comment: ok sorry about that

Comment: why not use an array modifier instead of the duplication method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the duplicate method post din your questions you can use an array modifier and a curve modifier.

**1. Add Curve**

- Add -> Curve -> Bezier
- move it (in my case I moved it along the positive x-axis)
- Place the origin at the start of the curve path

  - select curve -> edit mode -> Select start point -> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> Cursor to selected -> Object Mode -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> -> Origin to 3d cursor

  [image]

**2.**

- Add a plane at the same location
- Scale it down

  - edit mode -> <kbd>S</kbd>
- Apply Location: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> Location

[image]

**3.**

Select plane, add array modifier
Fit Type: Fit Curve
Relative Offset modify to move in the direction of the curve

[image]

**4.**

Add Curve modifier to plane

[image]

**5.**

Add mirror modifier

[image]

---

[image description http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=67294](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=67294)