# Placing spheres in a perfect circle on a ring

Tags: objects, bezier-curves

I am trying to place multiple spheres on a circle ring but am finding it really hard to get them into position. Is there an quick method to accomplish this or is there a tutorial that teaches such stuff.

Below is a quick illustration of what i want to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a single sphere, and a curve to the scene *(a Bezier Circle should do)*. Reduce the size of the sphere down to about `0.1` depending on the scale of the scene you're in.

Next, add an array modifier to the sphere and bump up the counts to about `10` or so you can see something. Finally add a curve modifier to the array of spheres. The spheres should follow the curve and you can now increase the array count depending on the scale of the sphere until both ends meet.

End result:

[image]

[image]

NB: If after doing this, the spheres don't connect at both ends evenly, just select the sphere in object mode and scale it slightly until they meet. You can also hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while scaling for more precision.

An alternative (but more cumbersome) way is to use dupliframes, see [How can I duplicate a mesh along a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve)

Comment: all the sphere are not similar shape . The front sphere are little bit elongated

Comment: @atek Right, not counting the example image which is due to perspective the size difference is negligible. See the new blend I attached. For an alternative, see the marked duplicate.

Comment: i think i was wrong i take my words back. Due to image i have seen so i said it. I was searching for my answer i have posted http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66272/how-to-rotate-object-along-path-path   can u plz help me to solve it

Comment: @atek see the link in my answer.

Comment: i have tried about the dupliframes but i was not successful. can u plz take my file and show me a demo plz

Comment: @ iKlsR as u have show me dupliframes i done with the path method but the problem is i cant delete the path and get the object to 1 single object i have posted my question plz go through http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66328/how-to-convert-path-to-an-single-object