# How to rotate object along path path

Tags: modifiers

[image]I have taken a sphere and a triangular path. I want that sphere to rotate along the path. I have added array modifier and curve modifier. It has rotate but the sphere lost its shape. I have applied rotation and scale to both object and curve yet to did not get the sphere in shape. How can i fix the issue. Whats missing or is there any other way i can do. Blend file attached ....... [image]

Comment: see similar questions, like http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65943/offset-object-duplicated-along-path

Comment: i don't want to animate that sphere. i want to fix that sphere in triangular shape. And not only triangular shape some other shape which have complex twist curve so that the sphere don't loose its shape.

Comment: sorry, but look at that answer: it is really similar, you just don't animate it: of course you need many more spheres (real or dupliverted). The point is that you don't deform the spheres but another "invisible" object ( eg. a simple segment), and then "link" your objects to it (eg: parenting + dupliverting)

Comment: sorry i didn't get what u mean can u plz show me a demo for my triangular to fix all sphere so that i can get the point how can i fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't need an animation (the word "rotate" misleaded me), you could do in this way:

- create a mesh "triangular" segment (33 vertices in my example), and add a sphere

[image]

- parent the sphere to the segment, clear its origin

[image]

[image]

[image]

- enable vertex duplication: any segment vertex gets a copy of the parented object

[image]

- then convert dupli to real, and delete or hide original object

[image]

[image]

This only works on mesh segments (vertices), and is very simple: let's see if this is enough.

Here is the workflow applied to your file:

[image]

To work on paths (curves) you need to use another approach, more like in the answer I suggested in comments above. It's more complicated, but gives a similar result for any shape you give to a curve (even straight lines or "triangular"). And, can be animated.

Comment: Thanks for brief explanation. I i made the model in wrong way. 1 question in mind hope u dont mind it. In the below explanation with my model u have explain. 2 edges the sphere are arrange good way and at the top side the sphere are arrange loose. May i know the reason plz. But what i mean to my question i got the answer about i want the sphere to be arrange in triangular shape

Comment: oh, that just depends on spacing of the vertices on each side (I just did a quick subdivision, so all sides have same vertices number, and on the long side the spacing is loose). Just put the number of vertices you wish on any side: you get one sphere for each vertex, anyway. To change vertices number, select all vertices and then press X > and "limited dissolve", you then have only 3 "basic" vertices, and you can subdivide each side as you wish, and retry if needed! Duplicated spheres will always match your vertices count and position.

Comment: Also see this answer it could turn useful, too: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7698/how-to-evenly-space-vertices